# How do i simulate an arrow key being pressed and held down then released? VBA

Tags: vba, sendkeys

Coding in VBA

I havent done much coding and im looking for a simple yet effective way to simulate an arrow key being pressed, held and released. Can you help?

The time the key is held for needs to be a random.next(x, y)

I want to stress by simple, i mean as simple as it can be please!

Comment: There isn't any "Easy" way to simulate key-presses in VBA. There are methods that might "usually" work, but probably not as simple as you'd like. Why do you need it simulated? Maybe we can help identify an alternative way of accomplishing *what the arrow key is being simulated for*

Comment: is there no way to do a send key with a hold or press and release?

Comment: If you are desperate, you can try looking into [SendKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.sendkeys); however, it's not known for being reliable, so you shouldn't expect it to work-as-expected all of the time.